# Create Google My Map from list of addresses

Tags: google-maps, geocoding

I have list of 25 or so addresses and I would like to create a Google My Map from them (so they are a set of placemarks). However, My Maps seems to allow creating placemarks only by drawing on the map with the mouse, not geocoding the addresses.

Is there a way to do this without writing any code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Log in to your Google account (not mandatory)
2. Browse to [Google Maps](http://maps.google.com/)
3. Search for the first address
4. Once located, click the pin and select "Save to.."
5. Select "Create a new map..."
6. Repeat 3-4 for next address, but save to the map you've just created.
7. Repeat 6 for subsequent addresses
8. Finally, edit the map: change the name, privacy settings and add comments for the specific addresses

For geotagging, you can just search for Lat-Long coordinates, instead of addresses (for example @32.39215,-112.096795)

Comment: Sweet, thanks! This works great for the number of addresses I have.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have the coordinates, you can easily put the points on Google Map - just copy/paste your coordinates to the following website: 
http://www.hamstermap.com and then go to Quick Map.

If you do not have the coordinates and only have list of addresses, just use the geocoder on the same website.