# Is there a fast way to create a map from a list of addresses?

Tags: google-maps

I have a list of about 100 addresses in Italy, and I’m wondering if there is a simple way to paste and visualise them on a map.

I have found these ways:

- Google Fusion Table
- Copy and paste on Google Maps

But the process is long in both cases.

Is there a faster way?

P.S.: I do not want to use a programming language.

Comment: How many addresses are we talking about?

Comment: 100 addresses  ..

Comment: And are they US addresses, or somewhere else?

Comment: italy. but if you have solution for us adresses post it.

Comment: For US addresses, you could try geocoder.us - they allow you to lookup one address each 15 seconds, but you can sign up (for a fee) to do bulk lookups.

Comment: Do you want a Google Maps-specific solution? Or something generic?

Comment: generic solution is ok

Comment: Related: [Create Google My Map from list of addresses](http://webapps.stackexchange.com/q/8200)

Comment: It says you can import up to 100 addresses in te "Lite" version: https://support.google.com/mapsenginelite/answer/3024836

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try http://www.torchproducts.com/tools/geocode/

There are also some (non-programming) solutions in the answers to a similar question at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/396819/geocode-multiple-addresses

Comment: :D man you created now this ?? :D look like you made it for me :D

Comment: No I didn't but thanks anyway :D